# Can't solve a circular import

Tags: python, import, module

I've read this [good text](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)  as a reference, but I still can't solve my circular problem:

```
import pygame
import python
import background
import player
import parser

class Game():

    map1 = parser.Parser("map1")
    map1.parse()
```

The parser.py module:

```
import os, sys

def replaceExtension(mapPath):

    # content

class Parser():

    def __init__(self, map, path="Maps/"):

        replaceExtension(path)

        # content
```

When I run my main file:

```
map1 = parser.Parser("map1")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Parser'
```

For some obscure reason it just does not find my Parser class.

Comment: Is that indention correct on your `__init__`?

Comment: if you import pythun you might have a hard time kek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in module called parser.
That's the one that gets imported. You need to rename your module.

You can find more on import order here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: So long as their in the same directory, shouldn't Python be using the local one first? I don't think that this is the correct answer. Just tested it out with a local file called `tempfile.py`.

Comment: Not really: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path